# How can I get workers to commute from other cities?

Tags: simcity-2013

[image]

This city is 80-90% industry but it is having problems getting workers. My goal is to fill those workers from the previous city that has about 100k since there is no commercial or industry in that city. But my problem is that only like 250-300 workers at any given time are commuting the other 2-3k are unemployed, any suggestions?

Comment: The first statement where is says here is my incoming highway, its actually referring to the above image

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site! In general, we prefer if you ask one question per question. You can also edit your question with the 'edit' button beneath your post, if you want to clarify something.

Comment: I just had a mini-tutorial that may be relavant. If I understood it correctly, you need to share the public transports (especially busses) with the neighbors for it to be used on the incoming highway. Are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for the input, and yea I have bus stations in the cities I wish them to commute to as well

Comment: Have the exact same problem ... but even worse. No one if traveling from one city to the other. I do however only have two small citites.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have found so far on this topic:

A small amount of sims will travel between cities for tourism/work on a daily basis, this is the 200ish that you are seeing.

If you want to do some level of massive commute then you need to provide an appropriate interface in both of the cities within the region. What I mean by this is if you have a ferry in one town then you must have one in the other town as well in order to have them be put to proper user. This goes for the other modes of commuting as well; the air port and the bust terminal (Not the shuttle bus, that is travel within the city).

Hope this helps.

Comment: yea i made sure that if the one had a train station then i had it in the other city same with buses and ferries

Answer (score 1):

By the book, the answer to your question should be simple. In order to get sims to commute between cities, you must provide adequate road, rail, sea, or air transport to move them effectively between two cities. You must also provide a commodity or opportunity that is in short supply in their home city, such as employment, education, or shopping.

Simply using the highway to allow sims to travel by car will not produce as good a results as using a Regional Bus Station in each city. For better results, a rail connection will move more people more quickly, and will not adversely affect highway traffic (though it will affect transit in the destination city due to the influx of workers). More advanced options will include ferry transport between cities with water access, as well as airports than can bring sims in globally.

**Right now, however, as of 03/12/13**, region play continues to be unstable and unpredictable. Monetary gifts between cities are being lost, even while still charging the city sending the gift. Cities are not being paid the appropriate monthly charges for providing power, water, and sewage. These issues are also affecting the transport of sims between cities for any reason, whether that is education, work, or tourism.

In short, it is difficult to answer this question right now. We know what the developers are intending to have happen, but we have yet to see it due to bugs and server strain. Once these issues stabilize, i will update this answer to something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Bus terminal and train does well but you have to support them with shuttle bus web.In your residential city if every bus terminal, train station and residential building can access to bus stops your citizens can make tranition between in shuttle bus and train station(also terminal buses) and they can go to bus terminal or train station, then do the same thing for your factories (support your factories, bus terminal and train station with shuttle bus web). At last come to regional view and have request for jobs from your residential city and system will work perfect. I have city with 25k population so far and this system can carry my population if you have trouble about capasity of the bus terminal and train station you can add ferry to your system too. 
Note** don't build bus terminal on your main higway because while passenger goes to bus terminal whole traffic is locking. If it is possible build roads just for bus terminal and build other bus terminals on this road too

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think after reading some stuff on the internet:

Somewhere on that Reddit site I saw a developer talking about commuting...

1. First of all the amount of workers, shoppers, kids, students is not the amount of residential/population. In the details map you'll see the numbers for workers, jobs and unemployed.
2. For workers (guess same goes for shoppers and students, but I don't know).

The maximum amount of possible worker_commuters = (amount unemployed - still open jobs in your city) / number of cities your city is connected to.

And with "cities connected to" that is any city your connected to by highway (and maybe even rail?) even though their is nothing in those plots. So many plots are automatically connected to 2,3 or more plots.

EXAMPLE

population: 100k, workers: 10k, unemployed 6k, cities connected to: 3

max commuting to city B from city A = (6k-0)/3 = 2k
Also, 2k will go to city C and 2k to city B.

3
a) they must have a reason to commute (of course) and b) must be able to, so no clogging up the highways and transportation like discussed above

I hope this helps. I would also like some comformation or repelling from others :P